# convert a key value object to a single array

Tags: javascript

I need to convert a object

```
{score: 77, id: 166}
```

to an array,

```
[77,166]
```

I tried,

```
Object.keys(obj).map((key) => [obj[key]]);
```

but seems like, it returns as 2 arrays.

```
[[77][166]]
```

Comment: `Object.values({score: 77, id: 166})`

Comment: You're returning the mapped data in an array. `Object.keys(obj).map((key) => obj[key]);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just had an extra pair of square brackets in your code

```js
const obj = {score: 77, id: 166};
const result = Object.keys(obj).map((key) => obj[key]);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use also use `Object.values(obj)` to achieve this result

```js
const obj = {
  score: 77,
  id: 166
}
const result = Object.values(obj)

console.log(result);
```

this will return you an array of values